# How Can I get messages in form of conversation from below table structure?

Tags: mysql, chat, inner-join, livechat

[image]

Here is mySql Table structure (pardon for errors its a legacy system) inbox_id is auto incremented primary key. I tried this query after some research but it is only giving latest message.

```
SELECT a.inbox_id, msg_to, a.msg_from, a.msg_title, a.msg_body

FROM  `inbox` as a

Inner join 
(
    select max(inbox_id) as id
    from inbox as alt 
    where alt.msg_to= 12
    or alt.msg_from='12'
    GROUP BY  least(`msg_to` ,`msg_from`), greatest(`msg_to` ,  `msg_from`)
)b 
on a.inbox_id = b.id
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: added mySql query.